# Whats the easiest way in C# to define a time of day, i.e. HH:MM:SS, without resorting to DateTime which requires year,month,day?

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to define a time of day, without necessarily specifying a year, month, day, which would require DateTime.

After I define this Time, I'd like to use all of the nice things about DateTime, i.e. AddMinutes, AddHours, .Hour, .Second, etc.

I guess what I really want the "Time" out of "DateTime", but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Many thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

This is what I was looking for:

```
// Specify a time of day.
TimeSpan timeSinceMidnight= new TimeSpan(16,00,00); // 4pm
... other code to calculate correct date ...
// Work out scheduled time of day.
DateTime date = new DateTime(2010,12,10).Add(timeSinceMidnight);
```

Comment: Wow! Why do you care? Memory tight?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you do `someTime.AddHours(48)` to a time object that has no date component? How would you later tell that the result was in fact greater than, rather than equal to, what you started with?

Comment: @John Saunders I guess I want expressive, clean code: I'd rather know that variable x refers to a time of day, rather than a specific date.

Comment: you should consider the fact that very few others have found this level of clarity to be necessary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just use the standard .NET `DateTime` class and ignore the date part?  It seems that `DateTime.ToShortTimeString()` could help, or perhaps `DateTime.TimeOfDay`, which returns a `TimeSpan` representing the length of time since midnight.

Any other solution would be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Having worked extensively with C# datetimes and formatting/calculation issues, I have to tell you that yes, the best way to get correct time calculations in C# is to just use DateTimes.  Timespans are also very helpful, but outputting a timespan in a custom format will require a DateTime (or a fair bit of manual code).

Comment: Brilliant - a combination of DateTime and TimeSpans does the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [TimeSpan structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me. **TimeSpan** represents a span of time, but without a specific **TimeOfDay** there's nothing that says you couldn't (by convention in the context you're using it) take it to mean a time rooted against midnight. I've seen and used **TimeSpan** this way. Extension methods namespaced to something not used by *all* of your code could also be added to validate that you're not creating a time of day like 13:24pm :)

Comment: Also, if you're really serious about conveying intent, you could also do **using TimeOfDay = System.TimeSpan**.

Comment: +1, TimeSpan makes sense as time since midnight, especially if you add a timespan to DateTime(year,month,date).

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have a datetime stored somewhere such as a database or you stored it in a variable manually. To strip out the time you can use this.

```
string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}");
```

edit: oops you meant keep the time not the date.